# How do I get a galleries cover image in modx revolution?

Tags: php, gallery, modx, modx-revolution

How do I get a galleries cover image in modx revolution?

Currently I'm calling the gallery by ID and limiting it to one image ~ however, this does not garantee that the image will be the cover image.

this is what I am currently doing.

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`[[!+tv.vehiclegallery]]` &toPlaceholder=`gallery` &thumbTpl=`homepageVehicleThumbTpl` &limit=`1`]]

[[+gallery]]
```

Comment: There is [cover_filename](https://github.com/splittingred/Gallery/blob/develop/core/components/gallery/model/gallery/mysql/galalbum.map.inc.php#L22) field at galAlbum model. It holds album's cover

Comment: Yes - but there is no way to specify ~which~ album you want with the galAlbum tag :(

Comment: I usually don't use these snippets. If I need an album by id I have to write getlist processor where it is rather easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed, the snippets do seem to have pretty limited uses. :( Different problem, same site, I have to output the gallery images twice on one page ~ the only way to do that is to call Gallery twice. Will have to write something custom for that too.

Comment: `I have to output the gallery images twice on one page ~ the only way to do that is to call Gallery twice`
You can use cacheManager for the output if it's the same each time. Something like [this](https://github.com/Fi1osof/modxSite/blob/master/core/components/modxsite/processors/site/web/getlist.class.php#L22)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is way more simple! I was looking at this for hours and couldnt figure it out, then it hit me. The cover of every album is always called "*cover.jpg*".
And it will be stored in the assets folder with the corresponding Album-ID.

Path abstract:

assets/gallery/[album-id]/cover.jpg

For example:

assets/gallery/1/cover.jpg

So as long as you have the Album-ID you can get the cover.

**Getting the Album-ID**

If you want the Album-ID heres one way:

1. Create a Template Variable called gallery_album with the input type galleryalbumlist.
2. Make it accessible to your preferred template.
3. Open up, or create a resource with that template.
   The Template Variable will be in the Template Variable Tab as a Dropdown containing
   all the previously created albums.
4. Choose an album from the dropdownlist
5. when you know call [[+gallery_album]] in the template, it will output the Album-ID

Code example: <img src="assets/gallery/[[+gallery_album]]/cover.jpg"

**Link to the modx extra Gallery:**

https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/gallery/gallery/index

Answer (score 0):

I would up doing this in a snippet instead:

```
    <?php

    //getgalleryAlbumCover

    $output = '';

    $sql = "select * from modx_gallery_albums mga where mga.id = $id";

    $album = $modx->query($sql);

    if (!is_object($album)) {return;}

        $data = $album->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // just in case ;)
        $modx->toPlaceholders($data);

        $output = $data['cover_filename'];

    return $output;
```